# Order bounded version of monotone complete $C^*$-algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, order-theory, cones

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra with self-adjoint part $A_{\operatorname{sa}}$. Then $A$ is called *monotone complete* if every increasing norm bounded net in $A_{\operatorname{sa}}$ has a supremum (with respect to the usual order on $A_{\operatorname{sa}}$ that is induced by the cone of positive semidefinite elements).
Since the positive part of the unit ball in $A_{\operatorname{sa}}$ is, when indexed over itself, an increasing net and an approximate unit, it is not difficult to show that every monotone complete $C^*$-algebra is unital.

If one wants to discuss a related completeness property in non-unital $C^*$-algebras, the following property seems natural to consider:

$(*)$ Every increasing net in $A_{\operatorname{sa}}$ that is bounded above by an element from $A_{\operatorname{sa}}$ has a supremum in $A_{\operatorname{sa}}$.

The sequence space $c_0$ and the space of compact linear operators on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space are simple examples of non-unital $C^*$-algebras that have property $(*)$.

**Question.** Has property $(*)$ been systematically studied in $C^*$-algebra theory? (And does it have a name which one can use to find literature about it?)

I did an online search and browsed through several papers and books that treat monotone complete $C^*$-algebras to find some hints, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\tilde{A}$ denote the (unique up to isomorphism) unitization of a non-unital $C^*$-algebra $A$.

Proposition 2.1.11 in [Saitô and Wright's monograph](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4471-6775-4) states the following:

> Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra without a unit element. Let $S$ be an upward directed set in $A_{sa}$ with supremum $s$ in $A_{sa}$. Then $S$ has a supremum $s$ in $\tilde{A}_{sa}$.

The authors give a proof on p. 14.

In light of this, it sounds to me like you are describing the non-unital $C^*$-algebras whose unitizations are monotone complete $C^*$-algebras. So the study of $C^*$-algebras satisfying your property should just be the study of monotone complete $C^*$-algebras (after unitization).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, Proposition 2.1.11 does not imply that $\tilde A$ is monotone complete if $A$ satisfies $(*)$. For instance, the sequence space $c_0$ satisfies $(*)$, but its unitization $c$ (the space of all convergent sequences) is not monotone complete.